# Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state. Check: Login > params.store.dispatch (Function)

Tags: react-native, react-redux

If I log in then I close application (and I have data saved in AsyncStorage) I get no errors when I'm trying to log out, but if I clear all cache/data from app and I try to login then to logout I have error:
**Non-serializable values were found in the navigation state.**

Index.js (extracted from file)

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'

function DrawerNavigator(props) {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} initialParams={{ store, logged: props.route.params.logged, userlevel: props.route.params.userlevel, usertype: props.route.params.usertype }} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default class App extends Component {
  constructor( ) {
        super()
        this.state = {
          logged: null,
          loading: true,
          userlevel: null,
          usertype: null,
        }
  }

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.getData();
    this.getToken();
  }

  getToken = async () => {
     store.subscribe(() => this.setState({ logged: store.getState() }))
  }

  getData = async () => {

    try {
      const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
      

      if(value !== null) {

        const myuser = await AsyncStorage.getItem('user')

        await axios.post(
          "api/usercheck",
          {
            username: myuser,
          },
          {
          headers: {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
          },
        )
        .then ((res) => {
          JSON.stringify(res);
          if (res.data.success === true) {

            this.setState({ 'logged': value, 'loading': false, 'userlevel': res.data.userlevel, 'usertype': res.data.usertype })

            store.dispatch({ type: 'OVERWRITE', payload: value }) //Redux Token
          }
          else {
            if (res.data.success === false) {
              alert ('User verification error.');
            }
            alert('User verification error.');
          }  
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          alert('No connection!');
        })
        .done()
          } else {
        this.setState({ loading: false })
      }
    } 
    catch(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
    
}

render() {

    if( this.state.loading ) {
      return (
        <>
        <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', }}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#ff0000" />
          <Text style={{textAlign: 'center', marginTop: 15 }}>Loading...</Text>
        </View>
        </>
      )
    }
    
    return(
    <>
      <StatusBar
            backgroundColor="#EE3A43"
            barStyle="light-content"
      />
      <NavigationContainer>
      {!this.state.logged ? (
        <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} initialParams={{ store, storeLevel, storeType }} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
        
        ) : (

          <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: true }}>
            <Stack.Screen name="DrawerNavigator" component={DrawerNavigator} initialParams={{ logged: this.state.logged, userlevel: this.state.userlevel, usertype: this.state.usertype }} />
          </Stack.Navigator>
        
        )
      }
      </NavigationContainer>
      
    </>
    )
  }
}
```

Login.js screen (login function)

```
login = async () => {
        if(this.state.username == '' || this.state.password == '' ) {
            alert('Fill username and password input.');
        } 
        else {
            axios.post(
                "api/login",
                {
                    username: this.state.username,
                    password: this.state.password,
                },
                {
                headers: {
                   "Accept": "application/json",
                   "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    }
                },
            )
            .then ((res) => {
                JSON.stringify(res);

                if (res.data.success === true) {
                    var mytoken = String(res.data.token)
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('user', res.data.user)
                    AsyncStorage.setItem('token', res.data.token)

                    this.props.route.params.store.dispatch({ type: 'OVERWRITE', payload: mytoken })
                }
                else {   
                    console.log(res.data)
                    alert(res.data.message)
                }    
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert('No connection!');
            })
            .done()
            
        }

    }
```

Profile Screen (logout function)

```
logout = async () => {
        try {
            AsyncStorage.removeItem('user')
            AsyncStorage.removeItem('token')
            this.props.route.params.store.dispatch({ type: 'OVERWRITE', payload: null })

        } 
        catch(e) {
          console.log(e)
        }
    }
```